# Send post request to Laravel App

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Trying to send post request via curl to my laravel app.
Getting  TokenMismatchException exception.
It is a post from one app to another so adding a token on a view is not an option.

Comment: Could you provide your Route definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default `csrf` filter available with Laravel. Can you print out `php artisan routes` to see if the route you want to access is protected by that filter?

If you want to access this route in production you might want to create a custom filter that checks for, or a csrf token, or a custom header that includes a secret.

Read `CSRF Protection` under http://laravel.com/docs/security#protecting-routes.
More info on CSRF on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: It was the filter, being applied to everything post.